# How much size of input folder can be given to the mapreduce program when the block size is 512MB

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using 4GB RAM.I have allotted 512MB of blocksize in hdfs-site.xml and I'm using CombineFileSplit Input Format whose max split size is 536870912 bytes(512MB).Then how much size of input folder can I give it to mapreduce program so that it will run smoothly without any out of memory exceptions.

Can anyone please suggest on this issue ...

Comment: Can anyone please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number of container are **dependent on the number of blocksize**. if you have 2 GB data of 512 mb block size, **Yarn creates 4 maps and 1 reduce**. While running the mapreduce we should follow some rules to submit the mapreduce job.(this should be applicable for small cluster)

You should configure the below property asper you RAM DISK and CORES.

```
<property>
    <description>The minimum allocation for every container request at the RM,
    in MBs. Memory requests lower than this won't take effect,
    and the specified value will get allocated at minimum.</description>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>512</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <description>The maximum allocation for every container request at the RM,
    in MBs. Memory requests higher than this won't take effect,
    and will get capped to this value.</description>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>2048</value>
  </property>


 <property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
  <value>2048</value>
 </property>
```

And set the Java heap size as per the Memory Resources.
Once ensured with the above property in **yarn-site.xml** according the mapreduce will succeed efficiently.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Out of memory errors occur because of several reasons. It is not possible to provide a input size which will not result in Out of memory errors. 
You better start using your mapreduce program, if you encounter any out of memory error, then somebody can help to resolve it.

HTH